# Is it possible to replicate Swifts automatic numeric value bridging to Foundation (NSNumber) for (U)Int8/16/32/64 types?

Tags: swift, swift2, nsnumber

### Question

- Is it possible to replicate Swifts numeric value bridging to Foundation:s `NSNumber` reference type, for e.g. `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64` and `UInt64` types? Specifically, replicating the automatic by-assignment bridging covered below.

Intended example usage of such a solution:

```
let foo : Int64 = 42
let bar : NSNumber = foo
    /* Currently, as expected, error:
       cannot convert value of type 'Int64' to specified type 'NSNumber */
```

---

### Background

Some of the native Swift number (value) types can be automatically bridged to `NSNumber` (reference) type:

> Instances of the Swift numeric structure types, such as `Int`, `UInt`,
>   `Float`, `Double`, and `Bool`, cannot be represented by the
>   `AnyObject` type, because `AnyObject` only represents instances of a
>   class type. However, when bridging to `Foundation` is enabled, Swift
>   numeric values can be assigned to constants and variables of
>   `AnyObject` type as **bridged instances of the `NSNumber` class**.
>
> ...
>
> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as `Int`
>   and `Float`, to `NSNumber`. This bridging lets you create an
>   `NSNumber` from one of these types:
>
> ```
> let n = 42
> let m: NSNumber = n
> ```
>
> It also allows you to pass a value of type `Int`, for example, **to an
>   argument expecting an `NSNumber`**. ...
>
> All of the following types are automatically bridged to NSNumber:
>
> ```
> - Int
> - UInt
> - Float
> - Double
> - Bool
> ```

From [Interoperability - Working with Cocoa Data Types - Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html).

So why attempt to replicate this for the `IntXX`/`UIntXX` types?

***Primarily:*** Curiosity, sparked by seeing some questions recently with underlying problems covering confusion over why an `Int` value type seemingly can be represented by an `AnyObject` (reference) variable, whereas e.g. `Int64`, cannot; which is naturally explained by the bridging covered above. To pick a few:

- [Why is a Swift Array<Int> compatible with AnyObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417438/why-is-a-swift-arrayint-compatible-with-anyobject/)
- [Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt32]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668775/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-uint32/)
- [Using generic arrays in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514268/using-generic-arrays-in-swift)

None of Q&A:s above mentions, however, the possibility of actually implementing such automatic bridging to `AnyObject` (`NSNumber`) from the non-bridged types `Int64`, `UInt16` and so on. The answers in these threads rather focuses (correctly) on explaining why `AnyObject` cannot hold value types, and how the `IntXX`/`UIntXX` types are not bridged for automatic conversion to the underlying Foundation types of the former.

***Secondarily:*** For applications running at both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, there are some narrow use cases—using Swift native number types implicitly converted to `AnyObject`, in some context—where using e.g. `Int32` or `Int64` type would be preferred over `Int`. One (somewhat) such example:

- [Why does this random function code crash on an iPhone 5 and 5S.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462750/why-does-this-random-function-code-crash-on-an-iphone-5-and-5s)

Comment: As of Swift 3, the fixed-sized integer types *are* bridged to NSNumber (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md, https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md).

Comment: @MartinR Alas, Swift's progress swiftly eats up these old hacky Q&A:s! Thanks for the prompt, will try to add some short note after work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes (it's possible): by conformance to protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`

*(The following answer is based on using **Swift 2.2** and XCode 7.3.)*

Just as I was pondering over whether to post or simply skip this question, I stumbled over [`swift/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift) in the Swift source code, specifically the protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`. I've briefly noticed the protocol previously at [Swiftdoc.org](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/_ObjectiveCBridgeable/), but in its current (empty) blueprint form in the latter, I've never given much thought to it. Using the blueprints for `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` from the Swift source we can, however, swiftly let some native of custom type conform to it.

Before proceeding, note that `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` is an internal/hidden protocol (`_UnderScorePreFixedProtocol`), so solutions based on it might break without warning in upcoming Swift versions.

---

**Enabling `Int64` bridging to Foundation class `NSNumber`**

As an example, extend `Int64` to conform to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, and subsequently test if this quite simple fix is sufficient for the implicit type conversion (bridging) from `Int64` to Foundation class `NSNumber` holds.

```
import Foundation

extension Int64: _ObjectiveCBridgeable {

    public typealias _ObjectiveCType = NSNumber

    public static func _isBridgedToObjectiveC() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public static func _getObjectiveCType() -> Any.Type {
        return _ObjectiveCType.self
    }

    public func _bridgeToObjectiveC() -> _ObjectiveCType {
        return NSNumber(longLong: self)
    }

    public static func _forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: Int64?) {
        result = source.longLongValue
    }

    public static func _conditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: Int64?) -> Bool {
        self._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source, result: &result)
        return true
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
/* Test case: scalar */
let fooInt: Int = 42
let fooInt64: Int64 = 42
var fooAnyObj : AnyObject

fooAnyObj = fooInt    // OK, natively
fooAnyObj = fooInt64  // OK! _ObjectiveCBridgeable conformance successful

/* Test case: array */
let fooIntArr: [Int] = [42, 23]
let fooInt64Arr: [Int64] = [42, 23]
var fooAnyObjArr : [AnyObject]

fooAnyObjArr = fooIntArr    // OK, natively
fooAnyObjArr = fooInt64Arr  // OK! _ObjectiveCBridgeable conformance successful
```

Hence, conformance to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` is indeed sufficient to enable automatic by-assignment bridging to the corresponding Foundation class; in this case, `NSNumber` (in Swift, `__NSCFNumber`).

---

**Enabling `Int8`, `UInt8`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, (`Int64`), and `UInt64` bridging to `NSNumber`**

The above conformance of `Int64` to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` can easily be modified to cover any of the Swift-native integer types, using the `NSNumber` conversion table below.

```
/* NSNumber initializer:               NSNumber native Swift type property
   --------------------------------    -----------------------------------
   init(char: <Int8>)                  .charValue
   init(unsignedChar: <UInt8>)         .unsignedCharValue
   init(short: <Int16>)                .shortValue
   init(unsignedShort: <UInt16>)       .unsignedShortValue
   init(int: <Int32>)                  .intValue
   init(unsignedInt: <UInt32>)         .unsignedIntValue
   init(longLong: <Int64>)             .longLongValue
   init(unsignedLongLong: <UInt64>)    .unsignedLongLongValue              */
```

Comment: You answer is almost perfectly comprehensive. But, as OP asks: why attempt to replicate this for the IntXX/UIntXX types? I don't see any advantage over directly use NSNumber constructor (initializer), which is available for every single Swift's 'number' type. For me the opposite is true, I hate 'free' automatic bridging. It is very easy to make a bug, because which value is used from NSNumber (as a container) is totally depend on programmer's wish. (no  'type-safe' checking more).

Comment: @user3441734 Note that I am the OP myself and that I answered my own question here :) Thanks for your feedback: although your comment is valuable in the discussion of ones _preference to auto. bridging_ (w.r.t. using `NSNumber` constructors directly), this Q&A mainly covers the _technical aspects of auto. bridging_, for those who are curious as well as those that prefer making use of the latter. But your point holds generally for most Swift<->obj-C interoperability: we take a step away from the strong type safety of "truly" native Swift code, and if not taking care, we might introduce bugs.

Comment: :-) You answer is almost perfectly comprehensive, and OP must be full satisfied!

Comment: But don't you think it's a bug that Apple doesn't just provide automatic bridging of these other numeric types? I do, and I have filed that bug.

Comment: @matt I agree that it's weird that we don't get this for free for the other numeric types. At the very least, all types (or none) conforming to `IntegerType` should have this bridging by default. Good thing that you've flagged this.

Comment: BTW you can delete those three occurrences of `@warn_unused_result` from your code - they are not needed.

Comment: @matt I see, I just kept them as a remnant from the Swift source that I got the template from. Will remove, thanks.