# Conversion operator in swift

Tags: swift, enums, type-conversion, typecast-operator

Is it possible to write custom conversion (casting) operator in `swift`? Especially I'm looking for enums conversion, ex:

```
enum MyEnum : Int {
    case Case1 = 0
    case Case2
    func __conversion() -> String { // doesn't work since Swift 1.0
        switch self {
        case Case1: return "Case 1"
        case Case2: return "Case 2"
        }
    }
}

let enumStr: String = MyEnum.Case1
```

Of course, I can convert to `String` with explicit method, but I would like to have implicit mechanism.

Comment: No, custom conversion methods were removed from Swift long ago.

Comment: @MartinR, what about `String` initializer with `MyEnum` input param?

Comment: Can't he make the enum a string type and use rawValue?

Comment: @Feldur I believe the source of this question is not how to modify the specific `rawValue` type of a given enum, but rather the potential conversion (ideally, for OP: implicit) to other given types (which are not the same type as `rawValue`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer/TL;DR! This answer pertains to the technical question as to whether **we can possibly** implement implicit bridging mechanisms between different Swift types ourself. The answer is: for some cases, yes, but only in a limited sense and by means of "hacks": do not use this is production code!*

#### Swift internal protocol abuse: we may implement implicit mechanisms to Obj-C objects (e.g. `NSNumber`, `NSString` ...)

As MartinR writes in his comment, custom conversion methods are not present for (native) Swift.

For the *technical discussion* we can, however, (ab)use the internal protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` to allow implicit bridging from your enum to Obj-C objects, in this case e.g. `NSString`. For a more detailed Q&A of the subject of the internal protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, see

- [Is it possible to replicate Swifts automatic numeric value bridging to Foundation (NSNumber) for (U)Int8/16/32/64 types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio)

Before proceeding, I'll quote a **disclaimer** from my answer in thread above:

> ... note that `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` is an internal/hidden protocol
>   (`_UnderScorePreFixedProtocol`), so solutions based on it might break
>   without warning in upcoming Swift versions.

---

***Example #1: implementing implicit bridging of your enum to `NSString`***

First lets add a failable initializer to your enum, allowing (attempted) initialization by `String` instances:

```
import Foundation

enum MyEnum: Int {
    case Case1 = 0
    case Case2

    init?(string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "Case 1": self = .Case1
        case "Case 2": self = .Case2
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Next up, let `MyEnum` conform to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, as described in more detail in the [thread linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517)

```
extension MyEnum: _ObjectiveCBridgeable {

    typealias _ObjectiveCType = NSString

    static func _isBridgedToObjectiveC() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    static func _getObjectiveCType() -> Any.Type {
        return _ObjectiveCType.self
    }

    func _bridgeToObjectiveC() -> _ObjectiveCType {
        return NSString(string: "Case \(self.rawValue+1)")
    }

    static func _forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: MyEnum?) {
        result = MyEnum(string: source as String)
    }

    static func _conditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: MyEnum?) -> Bool {
        self._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source, result: &result)
        return true
    }
}
```

With the conformance above, we can now make use of implicit bridging from `MyEnum` instances to `NSString`

```
/* example usage */
var myCase: MyEnum = .Case1
var enumNSstr: NSString = myCase // MyEnum -> NSString, implicit

print(enumNSstr) // Case 1

enumNSstr = "Case 2"

// NSString -> MyEnum, by type conversion (castable)
myCase = (enumNSstr as MyEnum) ?? .Case1
print(myCase) // Case 2
```

---

***Example #2: implementing implicit bridging of your enum to a custom Swift native type***

We may even abuse the `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` protocol further, using its (deep backend) mechanisms to implement implicit bridging between two native Swift types, with the limitation that the type bridged *to* must be a reference type (specifically: instances of the type must be representable by `AnyObject`, hence the reference type limitation).

Let `MyEnum` be as defined above, but additionally, define a reference (class) type `Foo`, and conform `MyEnum` to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` with the bridged *to type*, `_ObjectiveCType` being set to `Foo`.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: String
    init(bar: String) { self.bar = bar }
}

extension MyEnum: _ObjectiveCBridgeable {

    typealias _ObjectiveCType = Foo

    static func _isBridgedToObjectiveC() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    static func _getObjectiveCType() -> Any.Type {
        return _ObjectiveCType.self
    }

    func _bridgeToObjectiveC() -> _ObjectiveCType {
        return Foo(bar: "Case \(self.rawValue+1)")
    }

    static func _forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: MyEnum?) {
        result = MyEnum(string: source.bar)
    }

    static func _conditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(source: _ObjectiveCType, inout result: MyEnum?) -> Bool {
        self._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(source, result: &result)
        return true
    }
}
```

We can now make use of implicit bridging from `MyEnum` instances to `Foo`

```
/* example usage */
var myCase: MyEnum = .Case1
var myFoo: Foo = myCase // MyEnum -> Foo, implicit
print(myFoo.bar) // Case 1

myFoo.bar = "Case 2"

// Foo -> MyEnum, by type conversion (castable)
myCase = (myFoo as? MyEnum) ?? .Case1
print(myCase) // Case 2
```

Finally note that you may, for any given type (say, `MyEnum`), naturally only implement implicit bridging to a single other (reference) type; since you can only conform to `_ObjectiveCType` once (for a unique type for the typealias `_ObjectiveCType`), otherwise yielding a compile time error for redundant protocol conformance.

---

The above is tested for Swift 2.2.

Comment: thanks for so detailed explanation. Sad that it's hacking-way approach, but still very helpful.

Comment: @brigadir happy to dwell down into this subject! But again, as you also writes, these are hacks and shouldn't really be used in practice, even if it can be interesting playing around with them :)