# AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8-beta6

In Xcode8 beta6, the following code will cause a warning: 'is' test is always true. But it won't print pass.

```
    struct TestStruct {
    }

    //warning: 'is' test is always true
    if TestStruct() is AnyObject {
        print("pass")
    }
```

And the following code will cause a warning: Conditional cast from 'T' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds

```
public static func register<T>(_ protocolType: T.Type, observer: T) {

    //Warning: Conditional cast from 'T' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds
    guard let object = observer as? AnyObject else {
        fatalError("expecting reference type but found value type: \(observer)")
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler warn system bug. Structs can not conform to class protocol AnyObject

Comment: Nice find – you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org)

Comment: Thanks. Bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420

Comment: I saw your SwiftNoficationCenter some time ago and (unsuccessfully) tried to make that runtime check a compile time check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707450/function-that-takes-a-protocol-and-a-conforming-class-instance-as-parameters. But now (as I understand it) *anything* can be wrapped into an object (with weak references, as needed in your framework). So registering values as observer should just work.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work. Once the _SwiftValue is assigned to weak reference. The weak reference become nil. I don't know what happen in the underlying mechanism, But I don't think value type can be observed, because it's passed by copy.

Comment: @100mango: You are right, there is no strong reference to the object. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @100mango: This could work: `weak var weakRef = observer as AnyObject; guard let object = weakRef else { ... }`. – It is a horrible workaround though, and I don't know if it is reliable.

Comment: @100mango: Another option could be to change the function parameters to `func register<T>(_ protocolType: T.Type, observer: AnyObject) `, and check the protocol conformance at runtime, e.g. `guard observer is T else { fatalError() }`.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I am considering making T conform to AnyObject or the way as you propose.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object, perhaps that is a useful solution for your problem.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I will try to test it as soon as possible. I have created a Swift3 branch for SwiftNotificationCenter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***The warning works as intended: the `false` return of `TestStruct() is AnyObject`, however, does not***

The prior version of this answer perceived the warning,

> *'is' test is always true*

as the bug, and contained some discussion as to why this perceived buggy warning would manifest itself. That `TestStruct() is AnyObject` evaluated to `false` at runtime, however, was perceived as expected behaviour.

Given the comments to the [bug report filed by the OP (SR-2420)](http://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420), it seems the situation is the reverse: since Xcode 8/beta 6, the `is` test *should* always evaluate to `true`, and the bug the OP:s post is the fact that `TestStruct() is AnyObject` evaluates to `false` during runtime.

[Joe Groff writes](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420):

> This is correct, because everything bridges to `AnyObject` now.
>
> ...
>
> `is`/`as` `AnyObject` always succeed for all types now. It's behaving
>   as intended.

---

***The new `SwiftValue` box for conversion from Swift values to Obj-C objects***

*(for additional details, see discussion in the comments below, thanks @MartinR)*

It seems as if  Swift values that are not explicitly implemented to be bridgeable to Obj-C objects via e.g. conformance to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` (see e.g. [the following Q&A for details regarding `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490644/4573247)), will instead automatically make use of the new `SwiftValue` box to allow conversion to Obj-C objects.

The initial commit message for [swift/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.mm](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.mm) reads:

> **Runtime: Implement an opaque 'SwiftValue' ObjC class to hold bridged values**
>
> If there's no better mapping for a Swift value into an Objective-C
>   object for bridging purposes, we can fall back to boxing the value in
>   a class. This class doesn't have any public interface beyond being
>   `NSObject`-conforming in Objective-C, but is recognized by the Swift
>   runtime so that it can be dynamically cast back to the boxed type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I filed a bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420. The reason why I don't constraint T with AnyObject is that I created a framework [SwiftNotificationCenter](https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter) for one to many communication. And user will pass Protocol.Type as parameter.

Comment: @Hamish as always, thanks for grammar/typo corrections! :)

Comment: `struct SomeStruct { } ; let o = SomeStruct() as AnyObject` does *not* fail at runtime.

Comment: The magic seems to be in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.mm.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I don't have Xcode 8/beta 6 myself, so I never had a chance to try. Maybe I misunderstands your first comment, but note that I refer to OP's 2nd example (attempted `as?` conversion), when mentioning the expected (runtime) failed conversion (-> `nil`): `let o = SomeStruct() as? AnyObject` results in `nil` both in Xcode 7/Swift 2.2 and IBM Sandbox/Swift 3.0-dev (maybe _fail_ was a bad word choice in my answer). Does this attempted conversion succeed in Xcode 8/beta 6? Thanks for the repo link!

Comment: Yes, the cast from my above comment from a pure Swift value to AnyObject *succeeds,* and `type(of: o)` prints "_SwiftValue". That's how I found that source file. So it seems that arbitrary values are boxed as AnyObject.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, new magic in beta 6, didn't know about this. Just noticed that the bug report filed by OP had some activity, mainly linking to [this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/4410), with commits to, among other, the SwiftValue source you linked to above (description: _"Dynamic casts to AnyObject should succeed for an arbitrary source type because we can always make a SwiftValue."_). So seems as the warning in OPs question is not a bug, but rather the fact that the `is` test fails at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. As a final note, it seems as [`_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift) will still persist as detail-implemented implicit conversions, whereas the `_SwiftValue` box will be used if the prior is not available (for some given type).

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was an answer posted recently (by Rob Napier?) with a link to an evolution thread about making that bridging protocol public (which was postponed). But I cannot find that answer anymore.

Comment: @MartinR You're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/38837505/2976878 :)

Answer (score 6):

Long story short.

To check if value has a reference type:

```
if type(of: value) is AnyClass {
    // ...
}
```

To check if type is a reference type:

```
if SomeType.self is AnyClass {
   // ...
}
```

More helpful answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185374/746347
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546887/746347