# "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'AnyObject?'", Swift 3, Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift

A fairly simple piece of code

```
var dict: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
dict["key"] = "value"
```

generates the following compile-time error

```
Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'AnyObject?'
```

Simple type checks tell me that `String` is `AnyObject`

```
"value" is AnyObject // returns true
```

I could change `AnyObject` to `Any` and everything would work

```
var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
dict["key"] = "value"
```

but I want to understand why do I get the error? Is `String` no longer `AnyObject`? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In b6, String no longer magically bridges to NSString. String is not a class; it's a struct. You need to do the bridging by hand:

```
dict["key"] = "value" as AnyObject
```

The fact that `is` still seems to be bridging is likely a bug and should be reported.

It goes without saying that `[String: AnyObject]` and `[String: Any]` should be used as little as possible in your code.

(Make sure to follow the link Hamish provides in the comments below.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything was just as I suspected. That false-positive type check is the only reason why I asked this question.

Comment: [According to Joe Groff](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2420?focusedCommentId=17394&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17394), `is/as AnyObject` should always succeed, as everything bridges to `AnyObject` now. I believe this is due to that because `id` is now bridged to Swift as `Any`, `Any` can now be bridged to `AnyObject` (weird, I know).

Comment: And yes, looks like swift is experiencing AnyObject type check troubles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6

Comment: Can I ask you why [String:AnyObject] shouldn't be used in code?

Comment: @danielx0328 it is weakly typed, which creates a lot of opportunities for bugs and a lot of headaches for working in Swift (which is strongly typed). Most usage of Any or AnyObject bumps quickly into headaches in Swift.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for the response. So I use this simply since it is what Apple said was the preferred usage since it is shorthand. What is the way I should use it to avoid bugs then?

Comment: @danielx0328 I'm not aware of anywhere that Apple says AnyObject or Any are preferred usage. There are bridges into ObjC where it is currently unavoidable for temporary usage, but you should immediately convert these dictionaries to specific structs or classes.

Comment: @RobNapier "The type of a Swift dictionary is written in full as Dictionary<Key, Value>, where Key is the type of value that can be used as a dictionary key, and Value is the type of value that the dictionary stores for those keys. You can also write the type of a dictionary in shorthand form as [Key: Value]. Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form is preferred and is used throughout this guide when referring to the type of a dictionary." Straight from swift 3 documentation on their site. That's why I've used it that way :/

Comment: @danielx0328 I didn't mean the syntax "[Key:Value]". That absolutely is the correct way to write dictionaries. I am discussing `AnyObject` and `Any`. You should avoid `Value` being of type `AnyObject`. If you have a known set of keys (i.e. for a string-keyed Dictionary, there are only certain legal strings), then you shouldn't use Dictionary at all in nearly all cases; you should use a struct. The fact that Cocoa uses Dictionaries in some cases is a historic artifact, not a sign of good Swift.

Comment: @RobNapier okay now I understand! Okay thanks for that clarification! :)

Comment: [String:Any] is VERY useful when working with structured JSON/XML. Its only weak if you store unstructured data within it.

Comment: Only during parsing or serializing. You should as quickly as possible convert that `[String:Any]` to structs/classes for manipulation. It is weak even for JSON (in that it is capable of holding many values that are not valid values; which is fundamentally what it means to be "a weak type"). It is only necessary because of weakness in Foundation's JSON parser and serializer. It is completely possible to have a strongly typed JSON parser (such as the standard one in Go); Foundation just doesn't provide one, and it's difficult to build in Swift due to weakness of reflection.

Comment: This change does not result in equivalent code. It changes the meaning of the code in Swift 2 from Swift 3. In Swift 2 (without the `as`), assigning a `nil` results in the key not being added. In Swift 3 (with the `as`), the the value gets assigned.

Comment: The only way to get equivalence, AFAIK, is by adding an optional bind. This is useful if you happen to be converting a huge codebase that you didn't author to Swift 3 ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'll complement to [@RobNapier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045447/4573247) with some official sources.

---

The removal of the implicit bridging mechanisms was accepted in the following Swift evolution proposal, to be implemented for Swift 3

- [SE-0072: Fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions from Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md)

Previously, implicit conversions were available **from** some Swift native types **to** associated Objective-C types (Swift types conforming to private protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, e.g. natively `Int`, `String`, )

> For this reason, we decided to make a compromise. We would **require
>   explicit bridging casts** when converting **from** a bridged Objective-C
>   type **to** its associated Swift value type (E.g., NSString -> String),
>   **but not the other way around**.
>
> ... [From SE-0072]

With Swift 3, such implicit conversion mechanisms will no longer be available.

> With the introduction of Objective-C generics last year, along with
>   all of the awesome improvements to API importing happening for Swift
>   3, I think it’s time that we take another look at completing this
>   work.
>
> ...
>
> I propose that we **fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions in
>   Swift 3**. This would mean that some users might have to introduce
>   more explicit casts in their code, but we would remove another special
>   case from Swift's type system and be able to further simplify the
>   compiler.
>
> ...
>
> Code that previously relied on implicit conversions between Swift
>   value types and their associated bridged Objective-C type **will now
>   require a manual coercion via an `as` cast**.

Finally, [the release notes for Xcode 8 beta 6](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_6/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_6.pdf) (login required) states that this proposal has now been implemented for beta 6:

> ***New in Xcode 8 beta 6 - Swift Compiler: Swift Language***
>
> ...
>
> - Bridging conversions are no longer implicit. The conversion from a Swift value type to its corresponding object can be forced with `as`.
>     For example: `string as NSString`. Any Swift value can also be
>     converted to its boxed id representation with `as AnyObject`.
>     (SE-0072)

W.r.t. new *"boxed id"* allowing explicit conversion for any Swift value to `AnyObject`, see e.g. the following thread:

- [AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6/39034151#39034151)