# Swift: Why is this immutable?

Tags: swift, immutability

Can you tell me why this code does not work?

I have several arrays of `[AnyObject]` that contain UILabels and UITextForm.
This `func` should take as parameter an array and make all the labels and the text form disabled. I've tried with map, but still i have the same problem, the compiler tells me that or the variable is a constant or that is immutable.

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: inout [AnyObject]) {
    for i in 0...section.count {
        if section[i] is UILabel || section[i] is UITextField {
            section[i].isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many compile errors here

### Issue #1 (this is just a suggestion)

`inout` is not needed here because you are not mutating the `section` array, you are mutating the objects inside it instead.

### <strike>Issue #2</strike>

The `inout` should go before the param name (if you are using Swift 2.2)

### Issue #3

You should use `self` when comparing with dynamicType

### Issue #4

You can't write `section[i].isEnabled = false` because `AnyObject` has no member `isEnabled` so you should do a cast

### Issue #5

You are accessing an index outside of your array so this

```
0...section.count
```

should become this

```
0..<section.count
```

### Code Version #1

Now your code looks like this

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: [AnyObject]) {
    for i in 0..<section.count {
        if section[i].dynamicType == UILabel.self {
            (section[i] as? UILabel)?.enabled = false
        } else if section[i].dynamicType == UITextField.self {
            (section[i] as? UITextField)?.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Code Version #2

Since:

1. you can iterate your elements in a safer way
2. you should use `conditional cast` instead of `dynamicType comparation`

you can write in

> Swift 2.2

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: [AnyObject]) {
    section.forEach {
        switch $0 {
        case let label as UILabel: label.enabled = false
        case let textField as UITextField: textField.enabled = false
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

> Swift 3.0 (beta 6)

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: [Any]) {
    section.forEach {
        switch $0 {
        case let label as UILabel: label.isEnabled = false
        case let textField as UITextField: textField.isEnabled = false
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Code Version #3

Let's define a protocol to represents classes with an `enabled` Bool property.

> Swift 2.2

```
protocol HasEnabledProperty:class {
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}
```

Let's conform to it `UILabel` and `UITextLabel`

```
extension UILabel: HasEnabledProperty { }
extension UITextField: HasEnabledProperty { }
```

And finally...

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: [AnyObject]) {
    section.flatMap { $0 as? HasEnabledProperty }.forEach { $0.enabled = false }
}
```

> Swift 3.0 (beta 6)

```
protocol HasEnabledProperty:class {
    var isEnabled: Bool { get set }
}

extension UILabel: HasEnabledProperty { }
extension UITextField: HasEnabledProperty { }

func disableSectionForm(formSection section: [Any]) {
    section.flatMap { $0 as? HasEnabledProperty }.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I use if let or dynamicType?

Comment: @appzYourLife issue #6 AnyObject is pretty much dead

Comment: @matt what do you mean that AnyObject is pretty much dead? Why? and what should I use instead?

Comment: @AndreaMiotto: I believe _@matt_ means that the `UIKIt` methods are  generics since Swift 2.0. E.g. `UIView().subviews` no longer returns `[AnyObject]`, it returns `[UIView]`. So in your code (outside of this function) you should probably use something like this `[UIView]` instead of `[AnyObject]`.

Comment: @AndreaMiotto: I suggest you _Version #2_ or _Version #3_

Comment: @appzYourLife No, I mean that AnyObject is dead. Everything is Any now. Using AnyObject will cause your code to break because there is no longer any automatic bridging to AnyObject. So it's a good idea to get out of the habit of using AnyObject. (Of course, as you say, using UIView is a good idea in any case.)

Comment: Also `dynamicType` is now `type(of:)`.

Comment: Btw, *anything can* be bridged to AnyObject now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I also added the code for Swift 3.0 (beta 6).

Answer (score 0):

try to check if let block and use optionals

```
func disableSectionForm(formSection section: inout [AnyObject]) {
            for i in 0...section.count {
                if let label = section[i] as? UILabel {
                     label.isEnabled = false
                }
                if let textField = section[i] as? UITextFiled {
                     textField.isEnabled = false
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: happy coding @AndreaMiotto