# How to test whether generic variable is of type AnyObject

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 3 I am no longer able to check whether generic variable type is class (`AnyObject`) or not. Following code returns `true` for `isObject` even though specific type `T` and passed value is struct and not class. In Swift 2.3 and 2.2 it works as expected and `isObject` is `false`.

```
struct Foo<T>
{
    var value: Any?
    var isObject: Bool = false

    init (val: T?)
    {
        if val != nil
        {
            // following line shows warnings in Swift 3
            // conditional cast from 'T?' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds
            // 'is' cast is always true
            isObject = val is AnyObject

            self.value = val
        }
    }
}

struct Bar
{
    var bar = 0
}

let b = Foo<Bar>(val: Bar())

print(b.isObject) // -> true
```

How can I make it work properly in Swift 3?

Comment: Even `90 is AnyObject` returns `true`. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Related: [AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift 3, everything is bridgeable to `AnyObject` due to the introduction of [`_SwiftValue`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.mm) (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6) for more info), that can wrap anything that isn't directly bridgeable to Objective-C in an opaque Objective-C compatible box.

Therefore `is AnyObject` will always be true, as anything can be represented as an `AnyObject` via wrapping in a `_SwiftValue`.

One way to check whether a value is a reference type (as shown in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object)) is to type-check the type of the value against the metatype of `AnyObject`, `AnyClass` (aka `AnyObject.Type`).

For generics, if you want to check whether the static type of `T` is a reference type, you can do:

```
isObject = T.self is AnyClass
```

If you want to check whether the *dynamic type* of a value typed as `T` is a reference type (such as `val` in your example), you can use the `type(of:)` function on the unwrapped value, as the aforementioned Q&A suggests:

```
if let val = val {
    isObject = type(of: val) is AnyClass

    // ...
}
```

The difference between these two approaches is that when `T` is of type `Any` (or a non `AnyObject` abstract type), `T.self is AnyClass` will return `false` (which could be useful if you want a box where the value could be a reference or value type) – `type(of: val) is AnyClass` however, will return whether `val` itself is a reference type.