# Swift. Check if Any is value type or reference type

Tags: swift

Is it possible to check if an object (not as in OOP) is of reference type or value type?

```
let something : Any = getSomething() // func getSomething() -> Any
let isReferenceType : Bool = // how to check?
```

EDIT:
As pointed out this is practically a duplicate of [Check if `Any` value is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object)

Comment: `something is AnyObject`.

Comment: I’d like to see a use case for this. Seems like a Bad Smell.

Comment: Actually, it seems `is AnyObject` is always and it does not really work.

Comment: @Sulthan: Yes, a cast to AnyObject always succeeds. Discussed e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for commenting, I was actually trying to prepare for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907488/swift-extension-with-hierarchy-of-where-clauses

Comment: Then ask that, not this.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so easy as it seems, see

```
let isReferenceType: Bool = type(of: something) is AnyClass
```

See [How to test whether generic variable is of type AnyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546559/how-to-test-whether-generic-variable-is-of-type-anyobject)

However, if you need such things, then usually you have some big problem with your architecture that you should address instead. Using `Any` type should be the last resort for exceptional situations.

Comment: True, I am in the process of writing a more specific question about where clauses for extending dictionary.