# Swift strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash with objc_setAssociatedObject and objc_registerClassPair

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-access, associated-object

I face a very strange crash on Swift.

Xcode 11.3.1

Swift 5

## Case 1

```swift
class TestObject {
    var deinitExecution: (() -> Void)?
    deinit {
        // comment this to avoid crash
        deinitExecution?()
    }
}
private var associatedDynamicTagHandle: UInt8 = 0
class InterestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        guard let dynamicClass = objc_allocateClassPair(TestObject.self, "DynamicClass", 0) else {
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        objc_registerClassPair(dynamicClass)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(dynamicClass, &associatedDynamicTagHandle, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
    }
}
```

[image]

If I removed code `deinitExecution?()` or `objc_setAssociatedObject(dynamicClass, &associatedDynamicTagHandle, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)`. It works fine.

## Case 2

```
class TestObject {
}
private var associatedDynamicTagHandle: UInt8 = 0
class InterestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        guard let dynamicClass = objc_allocateClassPair(TestObject.self, "DynamicClass", 0) else {
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        objc_registerClassPair(dynamicClass)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(dynamicClass, &associatedDynamicTagHandle, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
        let method = class_getInstanceMethod(dynamicClass, NSSelectorFromString("aName"))
        print("method: \(String(describing: method))")
    }
}
```

[image]

If I removed code `objc_setAssociatedObject(dynamicClass, &associatedDynamicTagHandle, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)`. It works fine.

Is this a swift bug?

Comment: why you are calling completion closure in deinit ?

Comment: I cannot explain why it crashes, but making `TestObject` a subclass of `NSObject` seems to solve the problem. That makes some sense since you are working with the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: try to add if let or guard statement to check if it exist ?

Comment: In any case it would be interesting to know what the purpose of that code is.

Comment: @jawadAli: That makes no difference.

Comment: oh .. yeah it will be interested to know the reason ..

Comment: does it something to do with `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mis-use `objc_setAssociatedObject`. The documentation says:

> Sets an associated value for a given object using a given key and association policy.

The key point here is that you need an *object*, not a *class*.

The runtime functions `objc_allocateClassPair` and `objc_registerClassPair` just create new runtime classes, not objects. To get an object, you could use `NSClassFromString`, call `init()` and then associate the tag with it.

A complete running example could be (just a console program, no unit test):

```
import Foundation

class TestObject {
    var deinitExecution: (() -> Void)?

    required init() {
        print ("TestObject.init()")
    }
    deinit {
        print ("TestObject.deinit()")
        deinitExecution?()
    }
}
private var associatedDynamicTagHandle: UInt8 = 0
class InterestTests {
    func testExample() {
        guard let dynamicClass = objc_allocateClassPair(TestObject.self, "DynamicClass", 0) else {
            print("oops")
            return
        }
        objc_registerClassPair(dynamicClass)
        let toClass = NSClassFromString("DynamicClass") as! TestObject.Type
        let obj = toClass.init()
        obj.deinitExecution = { print ("deinitExecution") }
        objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, &associatedDynamicTagHandle, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
    }
    deinit {
        print ("InterestTests.deinit()")
    }
}

InterestTests().testExample()
```

with the following output:

> ```
> TestObject.init()
> one
> TestObject.deinit()
> deinitExecution
> InterestTests.deinit()
> Program ended with exit code: 0
> ```

Comment: Yep. I think you are right. `objc_setAssociatedObject ` only support object. Not pure class (objective-c class actually is an object but pure swift class not).
I am curious why `objc_setAssociatedObject` 's first parameter is `Any` not `AnyObject`?

Comment: They changed the mapping of `id` from `AnyObject` to `Any` during the migration from Swift 2 to Swift 3. I think the main reason is that _typical_ objects like `NSArray` are not objects in Swift but structs, so auto-bridging those types requires the use of `Any` in all those cases.

Comment: *Anything* can be converted to an object since Swift 3 (compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546887/1187415). In the case of a Swift `Bool` that is a `NSNumber`. So this alone does not explain the crash.