# How do I test whether a value is really an object in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2, it was possible to test whether a value is an object by using `is AnyObject`.

In Swift 3, however, all value types are automatically boxed in a `_SwiftValue` object when typecast to `AnyObject`. This means that the expression `x is AnyObject` is *always* true in Swift 3. The compiler will even warn about this:

```
'is' test is always true
```

Swift 3’s autoboxing of values comes with a memory allocation cost. **Is there a runtime test to determine whether a given value is an object in Swift 3?**

Comment: Indeed, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object. Funny that I couldn’t manage to turn that one up when I was searching for the answer! This version has more detail about _why_ this changed in Swift 3, but the essential question & answer are the same as that other one.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
func isObject(_ val: Any) -> Bool {
    return type(of: val) is AnyObject.Type
}
```

For example:

```
class Foo { }
isObject(7))    // false
isObject(Foo()) // true
```

In some quick performance tests, this function is at *least* 1000x faster than the memory allocation cost of `as AnyObject`. So it’s worth doing this test if special-casing value types can save you from having to wrap values as objects.

Comment: Note that, as of Swift 3.0, this breaks in optimized release builds when taking the type of an existential: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2867