# How the check if an variable is of type AnyObject in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm migrating a project from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 and ran into the following issue.

I have a function testing if a given input is of type `AnyObject`.
A simplified implementation could look like this:

```
func testIfIsObjectType(input: Any?) -> Bool {
    if input is AnyObject {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

In Swift 2.2, the following returns `false`.

```
let intValue = 3
let result = testIfIsObjectType(input: intValue)
print(result)
```

In Swift 3.3, it returns `true`.

The issue is caused by the fact, that all types (of type `Any`) can be converted to `AnyObject` now.

For example in Swift 3 you can now write:

```
let someType: Any = 1
let someObject = someType as AnyObject
```

Notice the `as` instead of `as?` or `as!`, which had to be used in Swift 2.

How do I check if the `input` is of type `AnyObject`, so the function will return `false` as in Swift 2.

**Solution:**

```
func testIfIsObjectType(input: Any?) -> Bool {
    if type(of: input) is AnyClass {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I searched for duplicates upfront, but was not able to find it, thanks for pointing me at this :)

Comment: @Hamish, the solution to the other question is no longer working. My question is about the Release Version of Swift 3, not beta builds.

Comment: Hmm, [the example in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object) given is still working fine for me in both Swift 3.0.2 and Swift 3.1 in both -Onone and -O builds. I assume the problem you're having is due to the fact that `input` is typed as `Any?` aka `Optional<Any>`, which is certainly not an `AnyObject`. Given the other Q&A doesn't answer this exact question, I'll re-open.

Comment: Really you just need to unwrap it, and the `type(of: input) is AnyClass` check should work again – `if let input = input, type(of: input) is AnyClass { return true }` should work.

Comment: @Hamish, you're right, I incorrectly used `AnyObject` instead of `AnyClass`. Thanks for letting me know. I edit my question, to show the solution.