# How to check if Error is subclass of NSError

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I want a function which, for any given `Error`, will give me some description of it

```
protocol CustomError { }

func customDescription(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case let customError as CustomError:
        return "custom error"
    case ???:
        return "not subclass of NSError"
    case let nsError as NSError:
        return "subclass of NSError"
    }
}
```

Above is not the real code, and I don't want a `String` description, but a `Dictionary`, but this is not important in context of the question.

The problem is I don't know how to distinguish `Error`s which is subclass of `NSError` and which is not because any swift error could be bridged to `NSError`. Is it possible in swift?

Comment: Something like `type(of: error) is NSError.Type` might work.

Comment: It is a similar problem as in [Check if `Any` value is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184911/check-if-any-value-is-object).

Comment: I'm not sure I see why you need to separate the `NSError` case from the `Error` case (they're specifically designed to be interoperable) – what is this `Dictionary` you're trying to get? (it does sound important to the context of the question). There's probably a better solution than trying to separate these two cases with casts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you already noticed, any type conforming to `Error` can be bridged
to `NSError`, therefore `error is NSError` is always true, and a cast
`error as NSError` does always succeed.

What you can do is to check the dynamic type of the value with `type(of:)`:

```
type(of: error) is NSError.Type
```

evaluates to `true` if `error` is an instance of `NSError` or a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

```
private protocol _NSError: Error { // private, so _NSError is equal to NSError
}

extension NSError: _NSError {

}

public func customDescription(_ error: Error) -> String {
    switch error {
    case let nsError as _NSError:
        print(nsError as! NSError)
        return "NSError"
    default:
        return "others"
    }
}
```