# Is it possible to detect a reference at runtime in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

Take the following code…

```
func f(p: Any) {
}
```

Can we know at runtime whether `p` is a reference or a value?

Now, to head off at the pass those who will ask, "Why, young Padawan, do you want to know this?" Well, it is a part of my further investigations into the Swift language.

Comment: Depends what you mean by reference; do you just mean whether `p` is a class instance? If so, you want `type(of: p) is AnyClass`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184911/2976878.

Comment: @Hamish That's right. Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Comment: Well aware of `type(of:)`. The secret sauce I was missing—obvious in hindsight—is `type(of: x) is AnyClass`.

Comment: @Hamish Doesn't that fail for ObjC bridged types? IIRC, `type(of: someStr) is AnyClass)` will be `true` because `String` would bridge to `NSString`

Comment: @Alexander I just tested that in the REPL and it did _not_ return true for a string.

Comment: @Alexander No, that'll be false because metatypes don't bridge

Comment: @GregoryHigley Import foundation first

Comment: @Hamish Oh, interesting

Comment: (after `import foundation`) `someStr is AnyObject // => true`, `type(of: someStr) is AnyObject // => false`. Checks out

Comment: Consider using `Mirror` - you can identify whether an `Any` is a class or not... I added my answer to the "duplicate" question, as I can no longer add it here.