# Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'UIBarButtonItem!'

Tags: swift, swift3

The following code used to be able to compile in swift 2.2, no longer in swift 3.0. How do we fix this?

> Error: Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'UIBarButtonItem!'

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if sender === saveButton { // Error!
        // ... 
    } else if sender === closeButton { // Error!
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simple compare with `==`?

Comment: Hello @EvgenyKarkan, because I don't want to compare the value of the these two objects. But instead, I need to know whether they are the same instance. See this for more details: [Swift also provides two identity operators (=== and !==), which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As the error message is saying. In Swift 3, Objecitve-C `id` is imported as `Any`, and you cannot call any operations for `Any` including `===`, without explicit cast.

Try this:

```
if sender as AnyObject? === saveButton {
```

(All the same for other `sender` comparison.)

And remember, in Swift 3, `as AnyObject` has become one of the most risky operations, you should not use `as AnyObject` in other cases.

Comment: how was `id` imported prior to Swift 3?

Comment: @Honey, Objective-C `id` was imported as `AnyObject`, and only some limited value types of Swift could be converted to `AnyObject`.

Comment: So their major diff is: *AnyObject is only for reference types (classes), Any is for both value and reference types.* ?

Comment: @OOPer, you mentioned in your question that "as AnyObject has become one of the most risky operations", could you explain a bit more why it is so risky?

Comment: @YuchenZhong, it can be a long article. First of all, you'd better read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39033194/6541007), carefully. And consider if you want to generate a `_SwiftValue` instance, when you use `as  AnyObject`.

Answer (score 13):

Try using optional binding with conditional cast to establish the type of the item before comparing:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let sender = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, sender === saveButton {
        // ...
    } else if let sender = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, sender === closeButton {
        // ...
    }
}
```