# Why would Error always be NSError?

Tags: swift, swift3, nserror

I have the following class defined on a Playground with Swift 3:

```
class MyError: Error {

}
```

Then, I create an instance of such class and check if it is a `NSError`

```
let firstError = MyError()
firstError is NSError // Output: false
```

The output is as expected, and I also get a warning which indicates `Cast from 'MyError' to unrelated type 'NSError' always fails`. This makes total sense for me, but if I change the code a little bit and declare the variable as an `Error`, I get a strange result:

```
var secondError: Error
secondError = MyError()
secondError is NSError // Output: true
```

And in this case I get a warning in the last line that says `'is' test is always true`. I don't get why an `Error` would always be an `NSError`, when the model is defined the other way round (`NSError: Error`). Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6

Comment: Because compiler is able to coerce `Error` to `NSError`. A quick search in Swift repo found this: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2fe4254cb712fa101a220f95b6ade8f99f43dc74/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift#L174

Comment: I was running into a similar issue while pattern matching NSErrors in switch statements. I found this blog post helpful: http://www.figure.ink/blog/2017/7/24/update-matching-nserrors
Apparently there is some funky casting of NSError to structs, not sure if this is applicable though.

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional behavior to allow Swift `Error` types to interop with Objective-C.

The compiler will only do the coercion when bridging Swift errors to Objective-C, or in your case where all you have is the `Error` existential that could contain anything... remember it could just as well have come from a `throws` function written in Objective-C. This also gives you an out to get the coercion if you need to pass an `NSError` directly to some Objective-C method as a parameter (for whatever reason).