# How to distinguish class in Swift 3.0(to be certain that it is not a struct or enum)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, value-type, reference-type

***How to understand if instance is value type or reference type?***

***DESCRIPTION:***

First of all, I've read about **AnyObject** in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

> Swift provides two special types for working with nonspecific types:
>
> - Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function
>   types.:
> - AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
>
> Use Any
> and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and
> capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about
> the types you expect to work with in your code.

So I've decided to write some simple code in my Playground:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var x = 5
}

let testStruct = MyStruct()

testStruct is AnyObject

if let object = testStruct as? AnyObject {
    //Do something
}
```

And I was shocked when saw 2 warnings.

> - 'is' test is always true
> - Conditional cast from 'MyStruct' to 'AnyObject' always succeedstestStruct is AnyObject

[image]

Even more... I was able to set my struct to the weak property.

```
class TestClass {
    
    weak var object: AnyObject?
    
}

var instance: TestClass? = TestClass()


instance?.object = testStruct as AnyObject
```

And I haven't seen any warnings or errors there. Will it cause crash or undefined behavior? It looks strange for me...

Also I mentioned types in the playground.

- type(of: testStruct as AnyObject) - _SwiftValue.Type
- type(of: testStruct) - MyStruct.Type

Probably testStruct was implicitly converted to class. But I'm not sure bout it, and can't any info about it on the internet =(

Have you ever read something about it? Or can you give me some link to the documentation to understand what is going on. Probably I missed very something very important.

- **Swift version**: Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
- **XCode version**: 8.2.1 (8C1002)

P.S.

I have to emphasis that it works fine(as I think) in Swift 2.0.

***Any way thanks for attention***

Comment: Compare [AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39033194/2976878) (dupe?) – *everything* is bridgeable to `AnyObject` in Swift 3. Things that cannot be directly represented in Obj-C (such as `MyStruct`) are put into an opaque Obj-C compatible box, `_SwiftValue`. A `weak` reference to this should be fine – although because in your example you're doing the boxing in the assignment, it'll be deallocated immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

```
type(of: value) is AnyClass
```