# Swift - pass escaping closure to C API callback

Tags: c, swift, closures

I have C API that I use from Swift.

In Swift, I have:

```swift
enum GetSnapshotResult {
    case success(snapshot: UIImage, String)
    case failure()
}

func getSnapshot(completion: @escaping (GetSnapshotResult) -> Void) {
    CAPIGetSnapshot(nil) { (_) in 
        completion(
            .success(
                snapshot: UIImage(),
                "test"
            )
        )
    }
}
```

And in C API:

```c
void CAPIGetSnapshot(void * ptr, void(*callbackOnFinish)(void *)) {
    //do something in background thread
    //and on its finish, call callbackOnFinish from thread 
    
    callbackOnFinish(ptr);
}
```

However, with this I get:

> A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

How do I solve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33260808/1187415

Comment: @MartinR I have tried it, but I cannot use `let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(completion).toOpaque())`. It errors with `GetSnapshotResult` not being class. I can create class wrapper and assign closure to variable, however, I am not sure what happens with `@escaping`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a wrapper *class* so that a void pointer to the instance can be tunneled through the C function to the callback. The combination of `passRetained()` and `takeRetainedValue()` ensures that the wrapper instance is released only after the completion function has been called.

```
func getSnapshot(completion: @escaping (GetSnapshotResult) -> Void) {
    
    class Wrapper {
        let completion: (GetSnapshotResult) -> Void
        init(completion: @escaping (GetSnapshotResult) -> Void) {
            self.completion = completion
        }
    }

    let wrapper = Wrapper(completion: completion)
    let observer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(wrapper).toOpaque())

    CAPIGetSnapshot(observer) { theObserver in
        let theWrapper = Unmanaged<Wrapper>.fromOpaque(theObserver!).takeRetainedValue()
        theWrapper.completion(
            .success( snapshot: UIImage(), "test")
        )
    }
}
```

Some remarks:

- I am assuming that the C function passes the `ptr` argument to the callback.
- `passRetained(wrapper)` retains the object. That ensures that the wrapper instance is not released when the `getSnapshot()` function returns.
- `takeRetainedValue()` in the closure consumes the retain. As a consequence, the wrapper instance is released when the closure returns.
- `completion` is a closure and closures are reference types. `wrapper.completion` holds a reference to that closure as long as the wrapper instance exists.
- Of course you can use the same variable names (“observer”, “wrapper”) inside the closure. I chose different names here (“theObserver”, “theWrapper”) only to emphasize that they are different variables, i.e. that the closure does not capture context anymore.
- `observer` needs to be a *mutable* raw pointer only because the first argument of the C function is declared as `void * ptr`. If you can change the function declaration to

  ```
  void CAPIGetSnapshot(const void * ptr, void(*callbackOnFinish)(const void *))
  ```

  then `let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(...)` works as well.
- For more information about conversion between object references to void pointers see for example [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift).

Instead of a custom wrapper class you can also take advantage of the fact that arbitrary Swift values are automatically boxed in a class type when cast to `AnyObject` (see for example [AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39033194/1187415)).

```
func getSnapshot(completion: @escaping (GetSnapshotResult) -> Void) {
    
    let wrapper = completion as AnyObject
    let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(wrapper).toOpaque())
    
    CAPIGetSnapshot(observer) { theObserver in
        let theCompletion = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(theObserver!).takeRetainedValue()
            as! ((GetSnapshotResult) -> Void)
        theCompletion(
            .success( snapshot: UIImage(), "test")
        )
    }
}
```

The forced unwraps and forced casts are safe here because you *know* what it passed to the function. A failure to unwrap or cast would indicate a programming error. But I would prefer the first version instead of relying on this “magic”.

Comment: Hi. In my case C calls the callback from a different thread. As a result `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` happens on the `theWrapper.completion()` call. Before I open one more question on SO - maybe there is a simple way to call swift callbacks from an async C library?

Comment: @Alexander: Generally, that solution should work even if the callback is called on a different thread. I think that more information is needed to solve your problem. You might want to ask a new question (ideally with a self-contained example demonstration the problem). – If you ping me here then I'll have a look at it :)

Comment: Sorry for longer response. You answered on the 24th of February and my life was quiet busy after that date :/ I ended up executing code from the callback on the main thread (as far as I understand it), so it works:
`DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`