# Swift custom type conversion by using `as` keyword

Tags: swift

for example, I have two classes, named `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`:

```
open class ClassOne {
    open var id: String?
    public init(id: String?) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

open class ClassTwo {
    open var id: String?
    open var title: String?
    public init(id: String?, title: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

then, create some instances:

`let one = ClassOne(id: "1")`

now, how to convert `one` to `ClassTwo` type by using `one as classTwo`?

I know I can implement a function like `public init(classOne: ClassOne) {}`, but I just wondering 'how to use `as` on custom types?'

I noticed something called `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, is there anything similar for pure swift types?

Comment: Do you mean *"custom type **conversion**"* ? – That are two unrelated types, there is no `as` conversion between them.

Comment: @MartinR yes, unrelated, but i'm wondering if I can implement some thing to convert them

Comment: And what would you expect that `(one as ClassTwo).title` evaluates to?

Comment: @MartinR maybe the `id` in `ClassOne, or `nil`. like `String` and `NSString`, they all have some thing special and unique, but `"string" as NSString` does works

Comment: "string" as NSString is *bridging* between Swift and Objective-C types, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio on how that can be replicated for other types (using "hidden" protocols). – Very early Swift versions allowed to define custom conversions between arbitrary types, that feature has been removed long ago.

Comment: Using type conversion between unrelated types doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user5685969 yes, that's right. but this is just an example. What I'm asking here is how to use `as` on custom types to convert instances.

Comment: @MartinR thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You don't, or rather, Swift can't.
(But in C++ on the other hand, you just need to create a constructor which takes the other type as parameter, and said constructor is called automatically (unless marked `explicit`).)

Your classes are not related in any way, programmatically speaking, however you have several solutions. For example:

**Solution #1: Convert**

You could add an init method to your ClassTwo, that takes a class one instance as a parameter.

```
convenience init(classOne:ClassOne) {
    self.id = classOne.id
    self.title = nil
}
```

You could also just have a non-init method that would do the same thing.

**Solution #2: Subclass**

Make ClassTwo a subclass of ClassOne

```
open class ClassTwo : ClassOne {
    open var title: String?
    public init(id: String?, title: String?) {
        super.init(id:id)
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

And now you'd see that you can use it interchangeably (but note that this can cause some headaches sometimes aswell):

```
func funcThatTakesA(classOne:ClassOne) {
}

let one = ClassOne(id: "1")
let two = ClassTwo(id: "id", title: "Instance")

funcThatTakesA(classOne: one)
funcThatTakesA(classOne: two) //It works!
```

Answer (score 1):

No: they are unrelated types (even if on the surface, they share a similar internal layout).

Even if it were C structs, you force-casted a pointer of one stype into a pointer of the other, and padding/alignment were such that the "common" member `id` had the exact same memory layout (same type and offset from start address of the object) in instances of both types, the second member `title` would certainly lie outside bounds!

Swift is very strict regarding types. In your particular case, you should either:

- Have both unrelated classes conform to a **protocol** that requires a property `id` of type `String?`
- Have `ClassTwo` inherit from `ClassOne`.

...and yet, either of these approaches will only let you cast an instance of `ClassTwo` into one of `ClassOne`, not viceversa (storage for the extra property `title` can **not** be magically synthesized by the cast).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, There is no relation between them so, first of all, you have to make the relationship in between two classes:
Here we show with the help of [inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_inheritance.htm):

```
open class ClassTwo {
    open var id: String?
    open var title: String?
    public init(){
    }
    public init(id: String?, title: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}

open class ClassOne:ClassTwo {
    public init(id: String?) {
        super.init()
        self.id = id
    }
}

let one = ClassOne(id:"hello") as? ClassTwo
```